# JDBC CallableStatement.execute() Hangs

Tags: jdbc, base64, varchar2

I am encrypting a `java.lang.String` using `javax.crypto.Cipher` and returning a `java.lang.String` via `return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedValue));`.

I previously tested the `CallableStatement.execute()` as working correctly with just `java.lang.String` and have recently changed the `CallableStatement.setString(int parameterindex, String x)` to use `new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedValue));` for the second argument.

This has somehow made the `CallableStatement.execute()` stall while debugging and the application quits debugging in Eclipse with no error.  The statement did not succeed by a quick check of the table I am modifying.

The table column type is `VARCHAR2` and now I am wondering if I need to perform some type of conversion from `Base64` to `VARCHAR2` and vice versa.

Comment: Please show your code (both the Java code and your stored procedure).

Comment: I had a DBA look into why the procedure was blocking and they unclogged  table with processes trying to execute.  Now I want to see if I have a `Base64` issue and, if it appears I do, I will proceed to post my code.